# SwiftUI NavigationBar back button complains about icon scaling when using custom font

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I see tons of logs when running my app telling me that the back button icon (chevron.backward) is being scaled.

```
2021-10-14 13:54:32.306371+0200 MyApp[37123:18219419] [framework] CoreUI: -[CUICatalog namedVectorGlyphWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:layoutDirection:glyphSize:glyphWeight:glyphPointSize:appearanceName:] 'chevron.backward' called with scaleFactor == 2.000000 glyphPointSize == 0.000000 at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreGlyphs.bundle/Assets.car'
2021-10-14 13:54:32.386602+0200 MyApp[37123:18219419] [framework] CoreUI: -[CUICatalog namedVectorGlyphWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:layoutDirection:glyphSize:glyphWeight:glyphPointSize:appearanceName:] 'UINavigationBarTitleTransitionBackIndicatorMaskSymbol' called with scaleFactor == 2.000000 glyphPointSize == 0.000000 at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/Artwork.bundle/Assets.car'
```

All back buttons in my app are created by the operating system, i.e. I don't manually add back buttons to the `NavigationBar`. I do, however, theme the `NavigationBar` by setting a font and foreground color to be used via a `ViewModifier`. Not applying the view modifier silences all logs, so I guess my usage of a custom font is causing those messages. The app is targeting iOS 15 onwards and I'm coding on XCode 13.

I call this View Modifier once in my `App`:

```swift
struct MyApp:App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      NavigationView {
        ContentView
      }
      .navigationBarThemed()
    }
  }
}
```

The `ViewModifier`:

```swift
// MARK: Navigation Bar
extension View {
  public func navigationBarThemed() -> some View {
    self.modifier(ThemedNavigationBar())
  }
}

private struct ThemedNavigationBar:ViewModifier {
  // MARK: Back button
  var backButtonAppearance: UIBarButtonItemAppearance {
    let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: Font.myFont.weights.regular, size: Font.sizes.navigationBarButton)!,
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.highlight)
    ]
    backButtonAppearance.focused.titleTextAttributes = [
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: Font.myFont.weights.regular, size: Font.sizes.navigationBarButton)!,
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.highlight)
    ]
    
    return backButtonAppearance
  }
  
  // MARK: Large Title
  var largeTitleTextAttributes:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: Font.myFont.weights.regular, size: Font.sizes.navigationBarLargeTitle)!,
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.text)
  ]
  
  var theme:UINavigationBarAppearance {
    let themedAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    themedAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    themedAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.background)
    themedAppearance.backButtonAppearance = self.backButtonAppearance
    themedAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = self.largeTitleTextAttributes
    
    return themedAppearance
  }
  
  init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = self.theme
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = self.theme
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = self.theme
  }
  
  public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
  }
}
```

**How can I use a custom font in the NavigationBar without causing these scaling logs?**

Answer (score 1):

**Not really an answer, but maybe helpful to anyone ending up here:**

I was not able to solve the issue with the above themed `ViewModifier`. Instead I created a `BackButton` view and an accompanying `.navigationBarBackButton()` view modifier which I use when I want back functionality in the navigation bar.

The back buttton:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BackButton: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.dismiss()
    }) {
      HStack {
        Text(Image(systemName: "chevron.backward"))
        Text("Back")
      }
      .font(myCustomFont)
      .foregroundColor(myCustomColor)
    }
  }
}
```

The view modifier:

```swift
// MARK: NavigationBar Back button
private struct NavigationBarBackButton:ViewModifier {
  public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(id: "navigationBarBackButton", placement: .navigationBarLeading, showsByDefault: true) {
          BackButton()
        }
      }
  }
}

extension View {
  public func navigationBarBackButton() -> some View {
    self.modifier(NavigationBarBackButton())
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView:View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ViewA()
        .navigationBarBackButton()
    }
  }
}
```